# spring-boot configure non exposed properties

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring-boot to configure jms and activemq connectivity. Due to a defect in activemq I need to set the idle timeout on the PooledConnectionFactory. This configuration is not exposed by spring-boot. How do I set it?

I have a @Bean to create a messageListenerContainer which has the connectionFactory as an argument. I can instanceof check the factory and configure it here but this seems not the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downcasting to `PooledConnectionFactory` and calling `setIdleTimeout` is a perfectly reasonable approach, in my opinion.

If you'd prefer not to do it as part of the creation of the message listener container, you could declare your own `ConnectionFactory` bean while still making use of `ActiveMQProperties`. Something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ActiveMQProperties.class)
class CustomActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ActiveMQProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = this.properties.createConnectionFactory();
        if (connectionFactory instanceof PooledConnectionFactory) {
            ((PooledConnectionFactory) connectionFactory).setIdleTimeout(1000);
        }
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was after. I had the same but missed the EnabledConfigurationProperties annotation on my config class. Perhaps if the PooledConnectionFactory was created using @Bean then it would be more straightforward.